# How to iterate through all utf-8 code points in a string

Tags: c++, utf-8, iterator

I would like to be able to iterate through all of the utf-8 characters in a string.

Imagine that all code points had a index, the first code point had index 0 and the last code point had index N. I want the iterator to be able to jump X indexes forward and also tell me the index of a code point.

I want to do something similar to http://www.nubaria.com/en/blog/?p=371, but I am not sure how to iterate over the bytes so that the iterators always refer to the start of a legal utf-8 code points.

Comment: be careful that there is no such thing as an "UTF-8 code point". UTF-8 is an encoding that represents **Unicode code points** in a byte stream.

Comment: Also, there's no easy way to iterate through all of the Unicode code points, and some of them are for internal use (are not standardized)

Comment: @MooingDuck Good point, I forgot that part.

Comment: The code points to iterate over are (roughly): 00000-​13FFF, 16000–​16FFF, 1B000–​1BFFF, 1D000–2B000–​2BFFF, 2F000–​2FFFF, E0000–​E0FFF, and F0000–​10FFFF.  And even in those ranges there's plenty of unassigned codepoints.

Comment: Thas exactly my problem, I am not sure of what ranges I need to itterate. 00000 is the start right? Where should I end? and how do I increment?

Comment: Also, be careful when printing them, if you start printing several combining characters in sequence you may get a big unreadable mess.

Comment: What that blog post does and what you're describing are very different things.  Your description makes it sound like you want to _enumerate_ ever Unicode code point.  The blog post is about _iterating_ through a UTF-8 string.  Please clarify the question.

Comment: @westberg you mention you want the iterator to "also tell me the index of a code point".  Which index, the byte-index or the code-point-index?

Comment: @westberg: Why do you want to iterate over the string?  Odds are, to do anything useful you'll have to have a much better understanding of Unicode first, and even then you'll probably simply translate it to UTF-32 before making modifications.

Comment: Oh wow. Originally I didn't bother checking the link because the description was clear enough, but now I realize your question as worded had **nothing** to do with your intent (or the link you gave). -1 for what is probably the most misleading question I ever saw. (and even that is quite an understatement)

Answer (score 5):

Warning: this method only works if you already know that your bytes contain clean UTF-8. It will not work properly in the presence of malformed or invalid characters.

The second through last bytes of a UTF-8 encoded codepoint will always have a bit sequence of 10xxxxxx. Skip over those and you'll be at the start of the next codepoint.

```
for (int i=0; i<X && *p!=0; ++i)
{
    ++p;
    while ((*p & 0xc0) == 0x80) ++p;
}
```

The `*p!=0` is there to make sure you don't run past the end of the string.

Comment: Sorry if I made it unclear, I want to itterate/generate all existing possible utf-8 code points. I am NOT intrested in itterating through a code point.

Comment: From what I understand can I look at the Roadmap to the BMP, http://www.unicode.org/roadmaps/bmp/ and see a table that goes from 0 to f horisontaly and verticaly from 00 to FF, but How can I itterate/enumerate through it?

Comment: At this site is it possible to view all blocks of possible encodings: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl I want to be able to generate all of them but I am not sure what is the legal was of stepping through/itterate all of them.