# Advance UTF-8/16/32 array by one character

Tags: c++, unicode

So, in UTF-8/16/32 we have the following issue:

```cpp
char8_t* test = u8"This is a Test containing the following german characters: ßẞ";
test++; // How can I do that correctly? This ignores the codepoints different sizes?
```

Can I define a function called `advanceUTF8(const char8_t*&)` that advances the pointer by 1? Has this already been done? Where? Better alternatives?

EDIT: What I want to know is how to advance the character by one user-visible character. So it should jump to the next character visible by the user. Also, my strings are 0-terminated, thus I want to know how to properly recognise a 0-terminated UTF8/16/32 string. Can I just check `*c == u8'\0'` and iterate over it or do I miss something here? (I do think both questions belong together, checking for 0-termination is impossible when not knowing how to advance through the string. I have added this because context was requested below)

EDIT2: I would appreciate a standard C or C++ solution.

Comment: `Can I define a function called advanceUTF8(const char8_t*&) that advances the pointer by 1?` Yes. `Has this already been done?` Yes.

Comment: Be precise, C++ answers will be different from "C" answers. Select ONE language

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18474971/21105992

Comment: Thanks for your input. However that does not solve all cases. AFAIK, characters can be composed of more than one codepoint. I will leave C and C++, because I think this question is relevant for both of them. I do not care weather it is a C or C++ one

Comment: Then use a library. Handling multiple codepoints gets complicated quickly.

Comment: You should explain more context. There are some things which can be done easily in some cases. In general case C and C++ sucks in handling encodings. Also which platform?

Comment: In C++ raw pointer arithmetic is not recommended and things like std::string_view/std::span and range based for loops are recommended. While "C" would likely use raw pointer arithmetic. So yes C++ might be able to compile the "C" solution is would still not be the recommended way of working. Also the libraries used for "C" and "C++" would differ.

Comment: You may want to read [Grapheme Cluster Boundaries](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries) followed by [Default Grapheme Cluster Boundary Specification](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Default_Grapheme_Cluster_Table), and decide whether you really want to implement this yourself instead of using an established Unicode library.

Comment: I am perfectly ok with a library compatible with either the C or C++ standard

Comment: Have a look at https://icu.unicode.org/

Comment: For C++, I prefer [Ogonek](https://github.com/libogonek/ogonek) over ICU. It's somewhat incomplete, and long-ago abandoned. For what it does, it's much better than ICU anyway (and what you're asking for here falls well within what it does quite nicely). By far its biggest problem is that documentation is nearly nonexistent, so you're kind of stuck with figuring it out from the test code (which, fortunately, is fairly extensive).

Comment: Possibly you should look something simpler. Maybe just a script (Latin?) (or few, including Greek and Cyrillic). A general solution would not be good (especially if you cannot fully test it): like fonts: there is a lot of special handling (for different languages): a generic format may not be feasible on this (and probably next) decade.

Comment: In C you can use `mbrlen()` if the LC_CTYPE category of the process's current locale has been set to specify UTF-8 encoding, but that is all implementation-defined.

Comment: A Unicode character is not a codepoint. This character ‍is three codepoints. This character ️‍️is five codepoints. This character ‍❤️‍‍is eight codepoints. The big question is why you need either.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: Pedantically, does Unicode define "character"? I think unicode would say that those _glyphs_ are composed of three codepoints, where each codepoint represents a _grapheme or grapheme-like unit_.

Comment: @MooingDuck it [does](https://unicode.org/glossary/#character), in several largely incompatible ways.

Comment: @MooingDuck OTOH glyphs are images or abstract entities representing one or more images. Unicode specifically warns against confusing characters with glyphs. If you are not rendering nor processing data for rendering, you are not dealing with glyphs. A codepoint does not in general represent a grapheme either. Each of the emojis above (and in general, every emoji) is a single grapheme (a minimal indivisible unit of the emoji writing system, uf it ever exists). A more down-to-earth example is the Arabic ligature ﻻ‎ which is a single glyph and a grapheme, but two code points and two characters.

Comment: Well the above is my understanding at least, which may or may not be correct as far as Unicode official definitions go.

Comment: A user-visible character is a *very* complex thing, way more complex than most programmers actually need. Why exactly do you need user-visible characters? Are you programming a text editor?

Comment: Nah, no text editor. I want to iterate over a UTF string, printing out the characters one-by-one. In ascii, this is simple (iterate until \0 is reached)

Comment: What kind of program are you making? For simple usecases, and if you control the strings being rendered, you might be able to get away with only allowing single-codepoint characters.

Comment: "I want to iterate over a UTF string, printing out the characters one-by-one." That doesn't make a lot of sense to me. What does it mean "one by one"? Do you want to print each one on its own line for example?

Comment: No example, no. This is an optimization for a special linked list I have in my usecase. I cannot provide any more details other than that the requirements are basically the same as if one would do a foreach loop while checking for 0-termination and printing out every characters.

Comment: "do a foreach loop while checking for 0-termination" is not a good requirement. What your users should *see* is a requirement. What you do to achieve that is just your implementation detail.

Comment: The user does not see anything but less memory usage.

Comment: Then you should do `int main(void){}`. The user does not see anything but less memory usage. No, really. You are optimizing some existing code. What user-visible things does your original code do? You seem to say that it should print something. What does it print? Can you show a screenshot or something? If the original code isn't written in terms of user-perceived characters, why should the optimized code be?

Comment: *"checking for 0-termination is impossible when not knowing how to advance through the string"* - That's correct, but you don't need to reconstruct code points for this. You can iterate over code units (which are fixed length) and check for one with a value of 0.

Answer (score 2):

The number of octets in a multi-byte UTF-8 character is trivially determined simply by looking at the first octet.

After [looking at the Wikipedia's UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) page and specifically at the table in the "Encoding" section, the logic should be patently obvious:

```
if (((unsigned char)*test & 0x80) == 0)
   ++test;
else if (((unsigned char)*test & 0xE0) == 0xC0)
   test += 2;

...
```

...and so on, for the remaining two cases. Put the above into your `advanceUTF8()`, and proclaim this mission as accomplished.

It goes without saying that a robust solution must properly handle an invalid encoding, and other malformed UTF-8 strings (i.e., in the case of a two-octet UTF-8 sequence do something if there's only one octet left in a string).

P.S.: the following alternative will also work, given the UTF-8 encoding pattern, as demonstrated in that Wikipedia page:

```
++test;
while (((unsigned char)*test & 0xC0) == 0x80)
   ++test;
```

Comment: It should be noted that the semantics of the two solutions offered are substantially opposite.  The first determines the code sequence length (for a valid code sequence) based on its first byte, whereas the second blindly consumes continuation bytes.  Both work fine for valid code sequences, but the two have different failure behavior for invalid code sequences.  The former better supports error *detection*, whereas the latter better supports error *recovery*.

Comment: Hm. If you're bold you could try something like `test += __builtin_clz(~(test&0x80))-24;` which is branchless. But probably not faster enough to justify the obscurity.

Comment: This is wrong. It advances by one *Code Point*, but the OP asked to advance by one glyph ("by one user-visible character"). For that, you'd need to identify *Extended Grapheme Clusters*. Examples of EGCs formed of multiple Code Points: g̈, 각, நி

Comment: @ikegami The original question doesn't mention glyphs. It mentions characters. The word "character" has four different meanings listed in the Unicode Glossary, and neither one corresponds to "glyph".

Comment: @ikegami This is not to say that advancing by one code point (or character or grapheme cluster or what have you) is *right*. Most people need to care about precisely none of those.

Comment: Re "*The original question doesn't mention glyphs.*", Yes it does. It asks to advance "by one user-visible character", which is the definition of a glyph. It's most definitely not a Code Point!

Comment: @ikegami A user-visible character is not the same thing as a glyph. You can find the definitions in the unicode glossary.

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI I had checked the Glossary. Apparently you haven't? "The actual, concrete image of a glyph representation having been rasterized or otherwise imaged onto some display surface."

Comment: @ikegami You are quoting the definition of *glyph image*. Which again has little to do with user-percieved characters.

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI, Re "*You are quoting the definition of glyph image*", Yes. And one of the definition of glyph is glyph image. "(2) A synonym for glyph image."

Comment: @ikegami You keep claiming that glyphs and characters are the same in some sense, but none of your quoted glossary entries support that. To give a concrete example, look at the usual characters `f` and `i`. If you stick them together like that: *fi* your browser *may* render them as a single glyph, the *fi ligature*. Or it may not. It is only interesting to people who deal with fonts and rasterization. So it may be a single glyph or two glyphs, but in either case, the two characters remain two characters, f and i.

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI, The glossary actually says the other way around that the fi lig could be rendered using multiple glyphs. Either way, your code does not address any of those issues.

Comment: I didn't give any code. As I keep saying again and again, user-percieved characters are way more complicated than most people realize or actually need. You can check how the cursor moves in e.g MS Word (you need to enable ligatures in font properties). The answer is: character by character. That is, f and i are separate even though they are clearly rendered as one fused image.

Comment: "the fi lig could be rendered using multiple glyphs" It could be, or it could be not. Depends on your font and the rendering engine. You should not be interested in how it is rendered, unless you are the one who does the rendering.

Comment: At any rate, glyphs are, conceptually, *pictures of pieces of text*. They are not characters. The glossary says: *Ligature. A glyph representing a combination of two or more characters*. Note, a single glyph, many characters.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as simple as it looks, due to possiblity of incomplete byte sequences at the end or invalid byte encodings. There is this [`std::mbrlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbrlen) et'al(also part of C standard library), who can test the next few bytes for validity and length, but due to possible unhappy results, higher abstraction into a simple function as you want may be not easy. I will just wrap the function into a monadic return function:

```
#include <cwchar>
#include <expected>
std::expected<std::size_t, bool> /*return the error state as 'bool'*/
u8next_idx(std::u8string_view str, std::size_t i){
     if (i > str.size())
         return std::unexpected(false); // false -> invalid
     std::mbstate_t multibyte{};  
     auto len = std::mbrlen
              ( reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&str[i])
              , str.size()-i, &multibyte);
     switch(len){
     default: return i + len; //happy path: next character index
     case -1: return std::unexpected(true); // true->truncated byte sequence
     case -2: return std::unexpected(false); // invalid byte sequence
     }; // !switch
}; // !u8next
```

Normally you'd keep and reuse the `multibyte` state over a full range of characters from begin to end. But in this snippet we are only interested in current byte.

Since this response targets mainly C++, I am very reluctant to pass raw pointers across function boundaries; Because raw pointers have ambiguous usage an confuse the reader of intended usage, leading to error-prone behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure what this does -- I'm guessing that it advances by one *Code Point* -- but it definitely doesn't advance by one glyph ("by one user-visible character") as the user asked. For that, you'd need to identify *Extended Grapheme Clusters*. Examples of EGCs that are formed of multiple Code Points: g̈, 각, நி

Comment: @ikegami yes. This is code tries to give the next code point. A glyph needs a lot more. I'd be happy to find if there's a standard function who can actually iterate over glyphs. I know there's a lot going on to fully support UTF in C++26, but the results are not ready yet.

Comment: Basically, you'd need to apply [UAX29](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/) and consult the Unicode Datatbase. There's surely an existing library for that?

Comment: @ikegami UAX29 says how to break text into (extended) grapheme clusters, which are useful approximations to user-percieved characters. But (as UAX29 itself says) the real life is more complex than that. There are circumstances where e.g. code points are closer to user-percieved characters than grapheme clusters. You really need to know the user's language and the mode of operation to decide. And for Pete's sake, (E)GCs are not glyphs. Glyphs are elements of *fonts*.

Comment: @ikegami as the other replies show, codepoints can even be detected using own bit manipulating code. I can't tell the same for glyphs or other forms of clustered bytes. This is what I hope makes it out before 2026: https://youtu.be/AoLl_ZZqyOk

Comment: That's a great video and a great piece of work, but I somehow doubt it all will make it to C++26.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI this is among what are always needed yesterday. We need something at that caliber. It's already too late.

Comment: I am not convinced. But this is largely off-topic here so I'll shut up.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, "What I want to know is how to advance the character by one user-visible character" does not have a simple answer.

The Unicode Standard defines user-perceived characters in terms of (Extended) Grapheme Clusters (EGCs). See the ["Q: How are characters counted when measuring the length or position of a character in a string?" Unicode FAQ entry](https://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html#7) for a brief introduction. EGCs are sequences of code points and code points are sequences of code units. A single `char8_t` value holds a single code unit. So, to advance a `char8_t` pointer from the beginning of one user-perceived character to the next entails decoding the code unit sequence and identifying the position one past the last code unit for the last code point of the current EGC.

The gory details of exactly how to do that are described in [UAX #29 (Unicode Text Segmentation)](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/). However, before settling in to read that document, I highly suggest you first read some lighter material on this subject first.

Henri Sivonen has a fantastic [blog post entitled "It’s Not Wrong that "‍♂️".length == 7"](https://hsivonen.fi/string-length/). Reading that will help ensure that the question you are asking is the one that you really intend to be asking.

As for a solution provided by the C or C++ standard, there is not one yet, but [SG16](https://github.com/sg16-unicode/sg16) has been working to improve Unicode support in the C++ standard and is expected to eventually propose a solution for code point and EGC sequence enumeration built on C++ ranges for a future C++ standard version. Stay tuned and help us if you can!